# Equalise heights of elements that do not share the same parent

Tags: html, css, rows

I know this answer has been asked already (in different way tho), but didn't find the answer yet.

So I have this structure:

```
<div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="row">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        2 <br> 3
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="row">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="row">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

How can I equalise the height of the rows inside the cols if they don't share the same parent?

Is there any way using CSS only?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? Flexbox? Etc.

Comment: What is meant by equalize? All rows to have height of tallest row?

Comment: @TylerH yes, I’m using Bootstrap, but that’s not relevant.

Comment: @Alexandru Actually it is relevant. I needed to know more details about your code (see [mcve] so that I know which questions to close this as a duplicate of.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava the rows should be the same height as the ones on the same line. For example col1-row2, col2-row2, col3-row3

Comment: this question should be reopened.  The easiest way to solve this is to change the orientation of the html and use flexbox.  Please vote to reopen so I can post solution